# How do I sort the last names , format phone numbers, and return a string containing values from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm working on this toy problem in JS, but I've been stuck for hours on how to proceed.

> Define an object constructor People that contains the values: full
>   name, email, phone number, age, and gender.
>
> Create four new People(names & values are up to you) and assign them
>   to an array.
>
> - Phone number and age should be numbers.
> - At least one full name should contain   a middle name.
>
> Then do the following:
>
> 1- Split the full name values into an array. 2- Format the phone
>   number: 1(123)456-7898 3- Sort contacts by last name. 4- Make a string
>   of each object and log it to    the console like so:
>
> Mr/Ms lastname, firstname | email | phone number
>
> a: Spacing should be the same for and fit all values. | b: Title, name, and phone number should be left justified. | c: Email should be right justified.

Below is my code. I made a function that is able to create an array with the name values, formatted the phone numbers into an array, sorted the names array by last name, but I can't figure out the logic to tie all this back to return a string. I believe it requires an if statement for the gender value. Can anybody help with the logic to answer this question? Here is my code. Thanks for reading.

```
function People(name, email, age, phone, gender){
  this.fullname = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.age = age;
  this.phone = phone;
  this.gender = gender;
}

// Assigning four new people obj to an array

var arr = [
  new People("John Doe", "jdoe@aol.com", 32, 15555555555, "male"),
  new People("Jenny Craig", "jcraig@netzero.com", 28, 19255555555,   "female"),
  new People("Bill Clinton", "bill.clinton@pres.gov", 59, 13105551234, "male"),
  new People("George Washington Bush", "gw.bush@gmail.com", 63, 15103456432, "male")
];


// Loop through array to access each obj fullname prop to split into array.

function nmStr(arr){
  var name = [];
  var num = [];
  arr.forEach(function(elem){
    name.push(elem.fullname.split(" ").reverse());
  });
  name.sort();
  arr.forEach(function(numb){
    numb.push(numb.phone.toString().substr(0, 1) + "(" +
    numb.phone.toString().substr(1, 3) + ")" +
    numb.phone.toString().substr(4, 3) + "-" +
    numb.phone.toString().substr(7, 4));
  });
  // console.log(name);
  // console.log(num);
}

nmStr(arr);
```

Comment: Is an extra `)` at `numb.phone.toString().substr(7, 4));` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I took a stab at it, I went a bit of a different way than you and I didn't do the final formatting, but I have it up to there I believe. For the last step to turn it into a string, I just loop over the final object and make a string by adding all the properties together:

JSBin...[Click, it will auto log my results](https://jsbin.com/melawa/4/edit?js,console)

Here is my code to manipulate the array:

```
function phonenumbermaker(num) {
  var str = num.toString();
  var re = /\(?(\d{4})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})/g; 
  var subst = '$1 $2-$3'; 
  var result = str.replace(re, subst); 
  return  result.substring(0, 1) + '(' +  result.substring(1,4) + ')' + result.substring(4);
}
var updated = arr.map(function(person) {
  var nameArray = person.fullname.split(' ');
  return {
    gender: (person.gender === 'male' ? 'Mr.' : 'Mrs.'),
    lastname: nameArray.pop(),
    restof : nameArray.join(' '),
    email: person.email,
    phone: phonenumbermaker(person.phone)
  };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.lastname > b.lastname) return 1;
    if (a.lastname < b.lastname) return -1;
    return 0;
}).map(function(p) {
  return p.gender + ' ' + p.lastname + ', ' +  p.restof + ' | ' + p.email + ' | ' + p.phone; 
});

// this part is just to log:
updated.forEach(function(finalThing){

  console.log(finalThing);
});
```

Comment: I only did this because it seemed like a cool problem. Could prbably be cleaned up further too...

Comment: little correction : person.gender = 'male' - use ===

Comment: `function(a, b) {
  return a.lastname > b.lastname;
}` [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Comment: @Omarjmh What does this mean? `var subst = '$1 $2-$3'; ` I've never used code like that before.

Comment: its part of  regular expressions. I don' think you need to it, here, if your phone number parsing works go with that.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for that link, I have updated the code... and book marked that link